# jqgrid select type searchoptions

Tags: jqgrid

I have a select type with values given below. The sopt is 'cn', so when I select 'approved' it gives me the results for 'Not approved' also, How can I get the exact match i.e.- Approved for Approved, Not Approved for Not Approved etc. Below is the code:

`var categories = ["All", "Approved", "Not Approved", "Pending"];
var categoriesStr = ":All;Approved:Approved;Not Approved:Not Approved;Pending:Pending";
var defaultCategory = "All";`

{name:'Status',index:'Status', width: 85,  stype: 'select', sortable:false,
                searchoptions: 
                { 
                    sopt: ['cn'],
                     dataInit:function(el){
                         var defOption = $("option:contains("+defaultCategory+")",el);
                         defOption.attr("selected", "selected");
                         setTimeout(function(){
                             $(el).trigger('change');
                         },500);
                    }
                },
                edittype:'select', editoptions: { value: categoriesStr } 
            }

Answer (score 0):

Deepti!

You can use the 'eq' operator.
This matches all values that equal to the dropdown value.